# set a threshold for complete cases to remove NA from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, na

There might be an easy answer to this, but I am not able to make it work. I have a data table that looks like this:

```
df <- data.table(t = c(1, 2, 3), a = c(NA, NA, 4), b = c(NA, 4, NA), c = c(NA, 4, NA))
```

How can I remove only the rows where all columns but "t" have NA's. It should be fast because of my big data files, so I would like to do it especially with complete.cases. I couldn't find a solution to this problem yet.

The result should look like this

```
dfRes <- data.table(t = c(2, 3), a = c(NA, 4), b = c(4, NA), c = c(4, NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete.cases` with `Reduce`

```
library(data.table)
df[df[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, complete.cases)), .SDcols = a:c]]
#   t  a  b  c
#1: 2 NA  4  4
#2: 3  4 NA NA
```

Comment: thank you very much! accepted your answer because it answers perfectly the question, even though the other solution of Ronak with rowSums works also great. thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` on columns other than `"t"`.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- which(names(df) != 't')
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[, ..cols])) > 0, ]

#   t  a  b  c
#1: 2 NA  4  4
#2: 3  4 NA NA
```

Comment: is it as fast as complete.cases for very big data tables with about 5 mio observations?

Comment: `complete.cases` is used to know which rows have no missing values. `rowSums` is pretty fast though.